# Fetch remote url from POST request

Tags: php

I'm looking for a way to fetch remote URL from where POST request was made to my form.
So i.e. I have a form on www.someserver.com/someform.html that does POST to www.myserver.com/some.php. So I need to fetch from POST request "www.someserver.com" on www.myserver.com/some.php page. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: do you mean you want to check the domain name that the post is being made from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The nearest you'll get is probably [`$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php). Be cautious though, as this is set by the user agent. From the API Reference Docs:

> The address of the page (if any) which referred the user agent to the
>   current page. This is set by the user agent. Not all user agents will
>   set this, and some provide the ability to modify HTTP_REFERER as a
>   feature. In short, it cannot really be trusted.